# Does $\frac{\partial}{\partial\epsilon}(\hat A+\hat{O}\cdot\epsilon) = \hat{O}$?

Tags: matrices, derivatives

I'm wondering does $\frac{\partial}{\partial\epsilon}(\hat A+\hat{O}\cdot\epsilon) = \hat{O}$ ?  Here, $\hat A$ and $\hat{O}$ refer to some operators which could be represented as matrices, and $\epsilon$ is some variable that takes real values. I think that's true from intuition, but I'm not sure if I could just treat those operators as some variables like $x$ and $y$. Thanks！

Comment: what's $\epsilon$? And then what would be your definition of $\partial/\partial\epsilon$?

Comment: Related: $\nabla(\vec{A}\cdot \vec{r})=\vec{A}$ for constant vector $\vec{A}$

Comment: Is $\hat{O}\cdot\epsilon$ a dot product, say $\sum_i\hat{O}_i\epsilon_i$?

Comment: @J.G. Yes, that's dot product:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@TurlocTheRed's point is that$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\epsilon_j}\hat{O}\cdot\epsilon=\frac{\partial}{\partial\epsilon_j}\sum_i\hat{O}_i\epsilon_i=\sum_i\hat{O}_i\delta_{ij}=\hat{O}_j.$$We define $\frac{\partial}{\partial\epsilon}\hat{O}\cdot\epsilon$ as the vector whose $j$th entry is $\frac{\partial}{\partial\epsilon_j}\hat{O}\cdot\epsilon=\hat{O}_j$, so$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\epsilon}\hat{O}\cdot\epsilon=\hat{O}\implies\frac{\partial}{\partial\epsilon}(\hat{A}+\hat{O}\cdot\epsilon)=\frac{\partial}{\partial\epsilon}\hat{A}+\hat{O}.$$